# PECL extension in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: php, mediawiki

I was installing [Mediawiki](http://www.mediawiki.org) on my local development machine and in the configuration, it told me that I will have to make do with slower loading tradition php pages because I dont have a PECL extension installed.

Does installing PECL really speed up page load times on a local server(or any server)?
If yes, can I please have a detailed tutorial on how to install PECL and configure it that says more than just `sudo apt-get install pecl-php`?

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get install php-pear php5-dev 
$ sudo pecl install pecl_http
$ sudo echo 'extension=http.so' >> /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

To verify it's installed run the following command

```
$ php -m | grep http
```

You should see `http` in the output.